# C# multiple tables, joins and custom columns

Tags: c#, mysql

Trying to join 2 tables together in C# on VS2015.

I can get the field id to match the field name but I want to calculate 4 fields into one header but I am struggling to do so.

this is the current statement I have.

```
var select = "SELECT fieldCosts.fieldCostID, fieldDetails.fieldName, fieldCosts.cropType, fieldCosts.cultivationCosts, fieldCosts.SeedCosts, SprayCosts as fieldCosts.spray1Costs + fieldCosts.spray2Costs + fieldCosts.spray3Costs + fieldCosts.spray4Costs FROM fieldCosts join fieldDetails on fieldDetails.fieldID = fieldDetails.fieldID order by fieldCosts.fieldCostID";
```

This is the full block of text for populating the Datagrid

```
var select = "SELECT fieldCosts.fieldCostID, fieldDetails.fieldName, fieldCosts.cropType, fieldCosts.cultivationCosts, fieldCosts.SeedCosts, SprayCosts as fieldCosts.spray1Costs + fieldCosts.spray2Costs + fieldCosts.spray3Costs + fieldCosts.spray4Costs FROM fieldCosts join fieldDetails on fieldDetails.fieldID = fieldDetails.fieldID order by fieldCosts.fieldCostID";

var c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=H:\School\Magee\Project\Programme\Farm Costs\Farm Costs\farmCosts.mdf;Integrated Security=True"); // Your Connection String here

var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dgFieldDetails.ReadOnly = true;
dgFieldDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

When I do the code without trying to calculate any columns it will show me all three fields but I only have one entry on the field.Costs table

Comment: Have you tried using Union statements?

Comment: Do you mean a join?